# Are there any function in C or C++ or WinApi to create directory including all unexistent directories in specified path?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, directory, creation

I need an analog of c#

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("d:\\asd\\dsa\\123");
```

which will create all that directories, even if disk D is totally empty with no any directories.

I read about WinApi CreateDirectory next thing:
**"ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND - One or more intermediate directories do not exist; this function will only create the final directory in the path."**
So it's not what I looking for..

Any other ways to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use `mkdir()` function  ? Another way to use:

1. [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm): supports standard MAX_PATH size 260.

   `const char dir_path[] = "c:\\temp\\cplusplus";`

   ```
   boost::filesystem::path dir(dir_path);
           if(boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir)) {
               std::cout << "Success" << "\n";
           }
   ```
2. [SHCreateDirectoryEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762131%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Win XP(SP2) and
   Higher. However, it is limited to 247 characters, which is less than the standard MAX_PATH (260) that other Win32 API filesystem functions support
3. [CreateDirectory function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855.aspx) : default string size limit for paths of 248 characters. This limit is related to how the CreateDirectory function parses paths. To extend this limit to `32,767` wide characters, call the Unicode version of the function and prepend `"\\?\"` prefix to the path.

**NOTE:** *Because most Boost.Filesystem operational functions just pass the contents of a class path object to the Windows API, they do work with the extended-length prefixes. But some won't work, because to the limitations imposed by Windows.* -- Boost warning.

Comment: `SHCreateDirectoryEx` is limited to paths with a maximum length of 247 characters. The boost filesystem is limited to paths of 260 characters, unless an extended-length prefix `\\?\ ` is supplied (`"\\\\?\\c:\\temp\\cplusplus"` in the example above). Certain boost filesystem functions that decompose their argument are still limited to 260 characters. If you need long paths you will have to roll your own using [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855.aspx).

Comment: Odd that `SHCreateDirectoryEx()` is limited to 247 characters, which is less than the standard `MAX_PATH` (260) that other Win32 API filesystem functions support.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. 2 points worth noting: **1:** `mkdir` has been deprecated beginning with Visual Studio 2005. An ISO C++ conforming implementation [`_mkdir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx) is available, but can create one new directory per call only. **2:** The way you described the boost filesystem reads like there are no length restrictions. [This is not the case](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#long-path-warning).

Comment: Thanks again for updating the answer. Although you did copy the note straight from the boost documentation it is plain wrong. The limiting factor is boost, not Windows. The section on the boost page goes on to explain what's wrong, but fails to stress the fact that it is boost, not the Windows API or the file system. It even makes false claims in that respect. Overall I would rate boost filesystem as a particularly low quality boost contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your particular compiler vendor provides its own RTL function for that purpose.  For example, Delphi/C++Builder has a `ForceDirectories()` function available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Perl/Ruby/Bash you would,

```
    `/bin/mkdir -p $pathname` #perl
    %x(/bin/mkdir -p #{pathname}) #ruby
    /bin/mkdir -p $pathname #bash
```

So you could evoke system,

```
    system("mkdir -p pathname");
```

Added:

Well, you want to split the given path into parts and make each part.  Easy enough to do in C (change char* and char[] to std::string, strcat to += for c++),

```
int MakeDir( char* pathname )
{
    struct stat sbuf;
    if( stat(pathname, &sbuf) < 0 )
    {
        mkdir(pathname,0); //set your permissions as you like in 2nd argument
        return(0);
    }
    else //exists? skip
    {
        //stat.st_mode tells file or dir
        if( S_ISDIR(stat.st_mode) ) { return(0); }
        else if( S_ISREG(stat.st_mode) ) { return(-1); }
        else if( S_ISFIFO(stat.st_mode) ) { return(-1); }
        else if( S_LNK(stat.st_mode) ) { return(0); } //can link to dir
        else { return(-1); }
    }
    return(0);
};
////char PATHSEP = "\/"; //unix/linux //not needed, just use 'mkdir -p'
char PATHSEP = "\\"; //windows
int MkdirPath( char *pathname )
{
    char parts = strdup(pathname);
    char buildpath[strlen(pathname)] = "";
    char* part = strtok(parts,PATHSEP);
    while ( part )
    {
        strcat(pathname, PATHSEP); strcat(pathname, part);
        if( MakeDir( pathname ) < 0 ) { break; }
        part = strtok(NULL,PATHSEP);
    }
    return(0);
};
```

Comment: Install cygwin/mingw :-)

Comment: I try to avoid windows